# In Haskell can I make numeric literals not polymorphic by default?

Tags: haskell, types, literals

This is probably not possible, since I already checked the list of all GHC extensions and this is not in there, but I thought I'd ask just in case.

Is there any way to make it so that `2` has type `Int` (or `Integer`) rather than the usual `Num a => a`?

(The reason I'd like this behavior is that it makes error messages clearer and type inference more likely to be possible (esp with type classes). I could always write (2::Int) everywhere but I'd rather the "more safe" behavior be the less explicit one)

Comment: yeah, don't do it :) the type inference usually isn't that bad. maybe if you post an example problem, people can help you work around it in a different way? you can set defaults via http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/numbers.html . you can also develop by prototyping the types of top-level functions by setting them to `f = undefined :: DesiredType`, and flush them out appropriately.

Comment: Polymorphic constants don't prevent me from doing anything -- but they do make error messages less direct, usually changing a "could not match expected type..." to a "no instance for...". Also defaults do not usually let you deduce an instance for a class (and feel like a bit of a hack)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a (slightly abusive and inconvenient) way to do this using GHC extensions.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RebindableSyntax #-}

import qualified Prelude as P
import Prelude hiding (Num(..))

fromInteger :: Integer -> Integer
fromInteger = id
```

In GHCi:

```
> :set -XRebindableSyntax
> :t 2
2 :: Integer
```

With the `RebindindableSyntax` extension enabled, GHC will use whatever `fromInteger` is in scope to handle numeric literals. The only constraint is that it must take an argument of type `Integer` (actually, even this isn't required, but if it doesn't you'll get a type error from numeric literals).

Note that, because the standard `fromInteger` is part of the `Num` class, you may need to hack some things around to get things working properly.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps it's best to only hide `fromInteger`: `import Prelude hiding (Num(fromInteger))`

Comment: Thank you! I tested this out and it does get exactly the behavior I want... though it is a bit wordy (it also makes arithmetic inconvenient but I never do arithmetic anyway).

Comment: @luqui: Perhaps. Not sure off the top of my head if hiding only that would have weird results using other functions in `Num`.

Comment: @Owen: You could probably try what luqui suggests. I was being a little heavy-handed hiding `Num` entirely, may not be necessary.

Comment: Yes, luqui's suggestion works; arithmetic becomes nice again. But I personally enjoy dispensing with aesthetic burdens like addition. I think I'll keep hiding Num ;)

Comment: @Owen: Hiding `Num` also has the benefit of letting you define arithmetic operators independently, instead of being attached to `Num`'s poor design.

Comment: @Owen: If you're not doing arithmetic, then what do you need numbers for?

Comment: @yatima2975 I'm just shoveling them around, mostly. Parsing arithmetic expressions.

Answer (score 4):

I think I should add "default()" to these answers, though I think gatoatigrado mentioned it in passing.  The Haskell 98 standard has a [section 4.3.4](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#default-decls) which eventually describes how to alter *some* defaulting of *Num a => a* values.  The implicit defaulting order is given by

```
 default (Integer, Double)
```

and can be changed, e.g. by putting

```
 default (Int)
```

or

```
 default ()
```

in the source file.